# Probability of a discrete variable depending on continuous variables

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, error

I have one random variable : $Y$ and a set of three parameters $\vec{X}=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. The variable $Y$ is discrete. I don't know its distribution and I am trying to extract it from data.

I am doing an experiment where for any choice of $\vec{X}$, the experiment can return either $Y=0$ or $Y=1$.

Thefore, I can define $N(Y=1 | \vec{X})$ as the number of events that returned $Y=1$ given some choice of $\vec{X}$. Similarly, I can define $N(Y=0 | \vec{X})$. Therefore, I define the probability of getting $Y=1$ given some $\vec{X}$ as

$$
p(Y=1| \vec{X}) = \frac{N(Y=1 | \vec{X})}{N_\text{tot}(\vec{X})}
$$
where $N_\text{tot}(\vec{X})=N(Y=1 | \vec{X})+N(Y=0 | \vec{X})$.

Of course, if the number of events is not high enough I cannot trust the numerical value of the probability. For example, for some given $\vec{X}$, I get the total number of events is small, let's say $N_\text{tot}(\vec{X}) = 2$, while for some other choice of $\vec{X}$ I find $N_\text{tot}(\vec{X}) = 200$.

For example, the following histogram is an example of $p(Y|\vec{X})$ in one dimension, i.e. $\vec{X}=X_1$. Orange bins collect the number of observations for which $Y=1$, while blue bins those for which $Y=0$.

[image]

What is a correct, rigorous, and standard procedure to maximize $p(Y=1| \vec{X})$ in $\vec{X}$, as well as reduce the statistical error due to low statistics?

Comment: If you know the relationship between your $X$ and $Y$, e.g., through a logistic regression, then this is straightforward (maximize the components of $X$ with positive coefficients, minimize those with negative coefficients). So it sounds like you are looking for a kind of an adaptive experiment plan to extract the relevant information from your observations, correct?

Comment: @StephanKolassa it's correct. I am trying to extract a confidence level for $X$ for which I can be confident that the experiment will return $Y=1$. Actually, I don't know the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, but I expect the values of $X$ for which the probability of $Y=1$ is 1 to lie on a compact region.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I see that in logistic regression, one assumes the logistic function, that converges to 1 at $+\infty$ and to 0 at $-\infty$. I don't think this function is a good ansatz for my case. Maybe I can use a higher-dimensional gaussian and just maximize the likelihood?

Comment: You have to assume *something* about the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, otherwise an observation at $X$ doesn't tell you anything about $X+\epsilon$, even when $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small. If you have some idea about the smoothness of the outcome, you can model it e.g. with a Gaussian process with the appropriate covariance function.

Comment: A [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is *precisely* how one models variables that can only take values in $\{0,1\}$. (Specifically, it models the *probability* for an instance to be $1$.) Why do you not think it is appropriate here? It looks to me like you are trying to set up an adaptive series of experiments to learn as much as possible about how $Y$ depends on $X$. One part of that will be the model, where a logistic regression would be what comes immediately to mind. The other part is choosing new values of $X$, where I don't feel qualified to help.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa If I understand correctly, there is an underlying assumption in logistic regression: the ansatz for the probability distribution. In my case, I expect the probability to be peaked around some value (for the one-dimensional example). The logit function is not peaked but smoothly goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa What ansatz should I use to fit my data?

Comment: If the probability for $Y=1$ is not monotonic in the predictors, you can use spline transforms of the predictors. Per above, it looks like your key question is how to set up an adaptive experiment, rather than how to model your data. (I may be wrong.) You might get more answers if you can edit your question to disentangle these two aspects.